# Exception while running xamarin ios app on devices only. The App runs on simulator perfectly

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using native ios framework in xamarin ios application. However i am getting an error while runtime. It throws below exception on device at runtime but it works smoothly on simulators.

**Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason:NSDate consoleOutputTimestamp.**

The reason might be, I was using a third-party NSDate category in my naive iOS framework. When I removed the whole NSDate third-party library. 
I was able to build it, however it throws a different exception this time. The exception is as below :

**Name:NSInvalidArgumentException Reason:UIViewController setIsFullScreen:**
**Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UIViewController setIsFullScreen:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145b3fd0**

Means every time I am making changes in native framework, after building it at runtime it throws an exception on devices only.
However the native iOS framework runs on devices in native iOS app smoothly.
However I am getting exception when I build it in Xamarin and runs it in Xamarin App. I have made changes related to architecture in Xamarin while building and in sample app as well but that didn't help. Do i need to make any changes in Xamarin project ?

I am using latest version of visual studio. The app stops at launch time and throws exception.

Please share if you have any idea about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the full exception? (Are these bad selectors?)

Comment: above i have prosted the full exception @Sushi

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes i think these are bad/unrecognised selector

Comment: `setIsFullScreen` : Using the deprecated MPMoviePlayerController? Or is `isFullscreen` a custom property?

Comment: Using the ALMoviePlayerController setFullscreen property @SushiHangover